# How can I create a row with text to the left and text to the right that will be compatible with all email providers?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the following design for an email:

```html
<table align="center" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
  <tr bgcolor="pink">
    <td align="left" width="50%" height="40px">
      Left Column Text
    </td>
    <td align="right" width="50%" height="40px">
      Right Column Text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But it doesn't work when forwarding the above table from Outlook to Gmail for example.
When I forward this email from Outlook, it adds extra elements to the `<td>`s:

```
<td align="left" width="50%" height="40px">
  <p align="right" style="text-align:right;">
    <span dir="RTL"> Some Text </span>
  </p>
</td>
```

And it makes the text align to the right on both columns. Why?

This is how it looks when forwarded from Outlook to Gmail: (Note that in the below example I manually changed the left column to `align="right"` just to mimic the behaviour)

```html
<table align="center" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
  <tr bgcolor="pink">
    <td align="right" width="50%" height="40px">
      Left Column Text
    </td>
    <td align="right" width="50%" height="40px">
      Right Column Text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Outlook you have to work with static pixels. The solution is to create an inner table specially for Outlook that does not appear to other email clients. Below you'll find a starting point for email clients.

It is important to style all elemnts inline (in the element tag) because some email clients remove the style in the `<head>` section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html style="border:none;" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
.ExternalClass { width: 100%; }
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div { line-height: 100%; }
#outlook a { padding: 0px; }
</style>
<!--[if (mso)]>
<style type="text/css">
td { font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif !important; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
<base target=_blank>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" style=" -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0; width:100%" width="100%">
<table style="-premailer-cellpadding:0; -premailer-cellspacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:300; margin:0 auto; mso-table-lspace:0; mso-table-rspace:0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td style="border-spacing:0; margin:0; padding:0 20px">
<!--[if (mso)]>
<table id="outlook" width="474" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; table-width:fixed;" align="center">
<tr>
<td class="outlooktd" style="width:474px !important;">
<![endif]-->
<table width="100%" id="mastbody" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" dir="ltr" style=" -premailer-cellpadding:0; -premailer-cellspacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; color:#444; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:300; margin:0 auto; mso-table-lspace:0; mso-table-rspace:0">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border-spacing:0; margin:0; padding:0">
</td>

<!-- here your email content -->

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border-spacing:0; margin:0; padding:0">
</td>
</table>
<!--[if (mso)]>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, I tried to use it but I'm not sure how to use this template to get to the style in my post. Do I need to copy the inner tables for every row I want? Or I just place my code where it says `<!-- here your email content -->`, or something else? because I just couldn't get it to work as per my style (text to right and text to the left). It still moves the left column's text to the right of it when I forward from Outlook to Gmail when I use your template, so I guess I use it wrong. Or I need this template for each column?

Comment: Note that the problem is after I send the email to Outlook then forward to another mail like Gmail (it looks alright in Outlook, even my original code)

Comment: To add to that, it works fine on the Gmail app, but it breaks on the web version

Answer (score 2):

Html emails are frustrating for anyone because there are so many email clients which show so many different results.

I looked into some professional email layouts and they are several kilobytes to result in a cross email client output.

Please try this (simplified) version with 2 columns (alignment left and right). Note that, for compatibilty reasons, the max width is set to 600px.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html style="border:none;" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" dir="ltr">
<head>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; font-family: sans-serif !important;">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no, date=no, address=no, email=no">
<base target=_blank>
<style type="text/css">
.ExternalClass {width:100%}
.ExternalClass,.ExternalClass p,.ExternalClass span,.ExternalClass font,.ExternalClass td,.ExternalClass div {line-height:150%}
table {mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-spacing:0px;border-collapse:collapse}
table td {border-spacing:0px;border-collapse:collapse;font-family: sans-serif !important}
a {text-decoration:none}
#outlook a {padding:0px;}
</style>

<table valign="top" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin: 0 !important; outline: 0; width: 100%; min-width: 100%; height: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 24px; font-weight: normal; font-size: 16px; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; color: #000000; margin: 0; padding: 0; border-width: 0;" bgcolor="#f7fafc">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td valign="top" style="line-height: 24px; font-size: 16px; margin: 0;" align="left" bgcolor="#f7fafc">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
      <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td align="center" style="line-height: 24px; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; padding: 0 16px;">
        <!--[if (mso)]>
        <table align="center"><tbody><tr><td width="600">
        <![endif]-->
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">
          <tbody>
          <tr>
          <td style="line-height: 24px; font-size: 16px; margin: 0;" align="left">
            <div style="margin-right: -24px;">
              <table class="" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;" width="100%">
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="line-height: 24px; font-size: 16px; min-height: 1px; font-weight: normal; padding-right: 24px; width: 50%; margin: 0;" align="left" valign="top">
                  <p style="line-height: 24px; font-size: 16px; width: 100%; margin: 0;" align="left">Text left align</p>
                </td>
                <td style="line-height: 24px; font-size: 16px; min-height: 1px; font-weight: normal; padding-right: 24px; width: 50%; margin: 0;" align="left" valign="top">
                  <p style="line-height: 24px; font-size: 16px; width: 100%; margin: 0;" align="right">Text right align</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <!--[if (mso)]>
        </td></tr></tbody></table>
        <![endif]-->
      </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you. I just tried and the text of the left column is still aligned to the right of it: https://imgur.com/a/bDys9gd

Comment: In your question you mentioned "forwarding from Outlook to Gmail". Unfortunately email clients will add their own html if you forward an email. When I look into the email-body after a forward, some specific html is added in Outlook as wel as Gmail.

Comment: Indeed that's why it's annoying. I thought that there can be some conditional values so that on Outlook it shows it only with Outlook html, and then when forwarded it will use the other html without the condition. But I guess that just don't work. But it's so weird because it's seemingly simple design - left and right.. like `flex-between` and that's it lol

Comment: Sadly email client does not support modern layouts with flex, grid or float. You have to use (x)html 4 with `<table>` for the layout, and inline style on all elements, and a dozen of bug fixes in the `<head>` of the email. Best practise is to center the content with a fixed width (600px) and use percentages. Margins is a 'better not use it' in the layout..

Comment: Oh yes I just referred to flex as to how simple to do is what I want with flex. I'm still not sure why the forwarding adds that extra HTML that breaks the alignment on the left column, making the text there align to the right instead of left. Driving me nuts

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain on html emails. As per another answer, Outlook needs very exact html and requires that basically everything be a table (or cell) in order to be forced to "behave".

*I have inserted a middle td instead* and have kept the alignment as left.

Try also always using full inline style as well on every single element (as mentioned in another answer) as well as copying all the css into the head AND the body.

I noticed that you weren't always using **style=""** in your example and this may be required (do not quote me on that). However, I suspect that the lack of styling may be making gmail misbehave as you said it is adding its own. It seems to think there is a span but you did not write one, therefore try using parargaphs and styling each one instead of just putting text in the td.

I added a bit more text just so I could see how it would look.

```html
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
        <tr style="background-color: pink;">
          <td align="left" style="width: 30%; height: 40px;">
            <p style="text-align: left;">
              Left Column TextUt maxime incidunt qui nihil iusto et
              necessitatibus odit sit soluta totam vel aliquam maxime ut iure
              nulla aut quaerat soluta?
            </p>
          </td>

          <td style="width: 30%;"></td>

          <td align="left" style="width: 30%; height: 40px;">
            <p style="text-align: left;">
              Right Column Text.Ut maxime incidunt qui nihil iusto et
              necessitatibus odit sit soluta totam vel aliquam maxime ut iure
              nulla aut quaerat soluta?
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. It does work to show the text on left and right. But the annoying issue of the left column breaking on forward remains. This is what happens when I forward from Outlook to Gmail and view on the web Gmail: https://imgur.com/a/7INLbPs. You can see that the text on the left column is no longer aligned to the left of it. (On mobile and Outlook it is still OK)

Comment: Sorry! As it is on forwarding only I don’t currently have any other ideas. The only other suggestion would be to set padding-left and margin-left to 0 on that paragraph.